# añadir object en object javascript

Tags: javascript, objeto

**obtengo un object  que es el return de una funcion en javascript, lo que quiero hacer es añadir un resultado al inicio y al final de la lista de resultados, como hago para combinar los 2 object y que el resultado quede como el ejemplo al final, gracias**

*el return es algo como esto*

```
{
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 29,
        "text": "carpeta",
        "icon": "far fa-folder",
        "color": "#000000",
        "state": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 116,
        "text": "carpeta2",
        "icon": "far fa-folder",
        "color": "#000000",
        "state": 2
      }
    ],
    "pagination": {
      "more": false
    }
}
```

*lo que quiero agregar es, algo como esto, al inicio y al final y combinar los 2 object*

```
{
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "text": "Nueva Categoria",
        "icon": "fas fa-plus fa-xl",
        "color": "#000000",
        "state": 2
      }
    ]
}
```

*para que quede algo asi*

```javascript
    {
       "results": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "text": "Nueva Categoria",
                    "icon": "fas fa-plus fa-xl",
                    "color": "#000000",
                    "state": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 29,
                    "text": "carpeta",
                    "icon": "far fa-folder",
                    "color": "#000000",
                    "state": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 116,
                    "text": "carpeta2",
                    "icon": "far fa-folder",
                    "color": "#000000",
                    "state": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "text": "Nueva Categoria",
                    "icon": "fas fa-plus fa-xl",
                    "color": "#000000",
                    "state": 2
                }
            ],
            "pagination": {
                "more": false
            }
        }
```

espero darme a entender, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede, como "results" es un array podes usar push y unshift para agregar elementos al final y al principio respectivamente:

```
let object = {
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 29,
      "text": "carpeta",
      "icon": "far fa-folder",
      "color": "#000000",
      "state": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 116,
      "text": "carpeta2",
      "icon": "far fa-folder",
      "color": "#000000",
      "state": 2
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": false
  }
}

let fragment = {
  "id": 0,
  "text": "Nueva Categoria",
  "icon": "fas fa-plus fa-xl",
  "color": "#000000",
  "state": 2
}

function addFrags(fragment, object){
  object["results"].push(fragment) // asi accedemos a la propiedad results que es un array y usamos los metodos
  object["results"].unshift(fragment)
  return object;
}

console.log(addFrags(fragment,object))
```

Comment: gracias, funciona perfecto

Comment: si la respuesta te sirvio marcala como "util". Saludos.